# Set up a contact database and sync it between iPhone and Android devices

Tags: contacts, sync, ios

Ideally, I like to have one centralized contact database. So if something needs updated, you only have to update it in one place and then it syncs to all the phones.

Thus, is it possible to set up a contact database and sync it between iPhone and Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same Google Account on both phones, you can use the system settings on both phones to sync your contacts with Google Contacts, also available via the web at [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com).

On your Android phone, go to:

> Settings -> Passwords & Accounts -> [Pick Google account] -> Account sync

and ensure the Contacts toggle is enabled.

On your iPhone, go to:

> Settings -> Contacts -> Accounts -> [Pick Google account]

and ensure the Contacts toggle is enabled.

You can find more detailed instructions for syncing contacts with your Google Account and your iPhone [here](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/2753077?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS) and your Android phone [here](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/9423168?hl=en).

If you're trying to use multiple accounts and just need the contacts replicated between devices with no Google (or other) account in common, your best solution may be to [export your contacts](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/7199294?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) and import them elsewhere.

Finally, if you're looking at doing this at a large scale, such as for many employees in a business, there are Content Resource Management systems that can accomplish this for a fee, one example of which is [Copper](https://www.copper.com/).